# Lua, Ascii String From Binary Value

Tags: lua

I have been reading [THIS PAGE](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)  (among others)  but still can't find my answer.

I'm trying to get Lua to convert an 8 bit value (i.e., an integer from 0 to 255) into a 2 Byte Ascii representation of the corresponding Hex chars

The only Lua syntax that I know how to use for this purpose is this one...

```
 MyString =  string.format("%1x", That_Number  )
```

... but, when the number is 0 to 15, that syntax gives me:  `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f`

... while this is what I really want: `01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F`

**My Question:**   Is there a simple syntax to guarantee me a "two digit" Ascii representation ?

("simple" means that it's already built into the syntax; not a function that I have to write)

p.s., it would be nice if I could get the `A, B, C, D, E, F` characters as upper case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string.format("%02X", 14))`

`0` for padding zeros instead of spaces.
`2` for a forced width of two characters (not `1` as in your example).
`X` for upper case letter output instead of lower case.

It should be pointed out that essentially none of this answer is Lua specific as those are [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) standard sequences and format options.

The [Lua reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.format) says:

> The format string follows the same rules as the printf family of standard C functions.
>   The only differences are that the options/modifiers *, l, L, n, p, and h are not
>   supported and that there is an extra option, q.

so we can infer that the `x` and `X` format specifiers are available with the usual width and leading zero modifiers intact.

The same principle applies to a number of Lua library functions. You will often need to refer to the related standard C runtime library function mentioned in the Lua reference to get a complete understanding.

Comment: Ta-Da, thank you Etan. I tried the "02X" as you suggested (with upper case "X" instead of lower, and the leading "0") and all is fixed.  Smart guy.  Thanks

Comment: I boldly extended your very fine answer with links to `printf` and `string.format` documentation in hopes that this sort of thing will help future folks finding this question. Extending yours seemed fairer than adding a redundant answer of my own...

Comment: @RBerteig Good additions. Thanks.